# How can I read a huge file JSON with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I'm trying to read a json file regarding my scheduling lessons at university, getting it from this link : http://diag.uniroma1.it/pannello/?q=export_json

I tried to do it using https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple which works for very simple json file as in https://helloacm.com/api/factor/?cached&n=10 ( where given a number it returns the factorization of itself).

But applying same reasoning doesn't works. Actually the application that first that previously worked well, now crashes.

```
 fun factors (x: String){

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        //val url = "https://helloacm.com/api/factor/?cached&n="+x

        val url = "http://diag.uniroma1.it/pannello/?q=export_json"

        var reply : String = ""

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                reply = JSONObject(response.toString()).toString()
                output.text=reply
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error: VolleyError? ->  output.text = error.toString() })

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest)

    }
```

What is the problem? Is the file too big respect the previous one? I'm really new in this stuff

Comment: Can you share the crash logs? If it's crashing, I don't think it's anything to do with the file size. There is probably some other RuntimeException.

Comment: @Rachit I run it on my smartphone and when I press the button to get the response, application stops and appears : "application_name has stopped  Open app again"

Comment: you can check for the crash logs by running the app on the phone, and going to the Logcat tab on Android Studio. When the crash occurs, you'll see the reason for the crash.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it does not work is that you are receiving a JSON array but you are trying to parse it as a JSON object.

In order to simplify deserialization, you can check [Google's Gson Library](https://github.com/google/gson).
Here's an example of Gson implementation:

1. Add the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file and sync your project with Gradle:

   ```
   implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
   ```
2. Create a model that represents your JSON objects:

   ```
   import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

   data class DataObject(
       @SerializedName("data")
       val data: String,
       @SerializedName("Descrizione")
       val descrizione: String,
       @SerializedName("Id")
       val id: String,
       @SerializedName("id_aula")
       val idAula: String,
       @SerializedName("minuti_fine")
       val minutiFine: String,
       @SerializedName("minuti_inizio")
       val minutiInizio: String,
       @SerializedName("nome_aula")
       val nomeAula: String,
       @SerializedName("ora_fine")
       val oraFine: String,
       @SerializedName("ora_inizio")
       val oraInizio: String
   )
   ```
3. Now you can modify your function to deserialize JSON:

   ```
   fun factors(x: String) {

       val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
       //val url = "https://helloacm.com/api/factor/?cached&n="+x

       val url = "http://diag.uniroma1.it/pannello/?q=export_json"

       var reply: List<DataObject> = listOf()

       // Request a string response from the provided URL.
       val stringRequest = StringRequest(
               Request.Method.GET, url,
               Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                   // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                   reply = Gson().fromJson(response, object : TypeToken<List<DataObject>>() {}.type)
                   output.text = reply
               },
               Response.ErrorListener { error: VolleyError? -> output.text = error.toString() })

       // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
       queue.add(stringRequest)
   }
   ```